# Where is .app file for iOS in Flutter app?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, code-signing

From this page, https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663271 I want to run this command: `codesign -d --entitlements :- /path/to/your.app | grep -A 1 "com.apple.developer.networking.multicast"` but I can't find `/path/to/your.app` in my computer. Where can I find .app file?

Answer (score 2):

Check the below path.

```
/Your_project_Dir/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you compiled it, I'd generate an archive then you can open the archive and see the compiled .app

Or you could compile from terminal with xcodebuild then it'll be under `build`